# what is the better way to implement auditing in redis cache (using redis as persistant storage) in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redisson, data-persistence

**Audit class** :

```
public class Audit {
    private Long createdDateTime;
    private Long updatedDateTime;
    private String createdBy;
    private String updatedBy;
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class User extends Audit {
  

}
```

Is there a way to listen to Entity update/create event in spring redis?

Comment: As I understand, redis is your only persistence? What's the problem with using hibernate envers then?

Answer (score 0):

As of now update/create events can only be captured in spring-data-jpa. Why don't you use spring-data-jpa as the permanent store since it has more built in functionalities and redis as a cache store?

Comment: using redisson instead of Jedis(spring data)